# Gulp cryptic build error on /dist assembly

Tags: build, gulp, instanceof, exitstatus, gulp-usemin

Has anyone receive this kind of error or can tell me what is going on here?

```
[11:11:44] Finished 'build-css-no-source' after 531 ms
[11:11:44] Starting 'move-to-dist'...

/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-iconfont/node_modules/gulp-ttf2woff2/node_modules/ttf2woff2/jssrc/ttf2woff2.js:1
aughtException",(function(ex){if(!(ex instanceof ExitStatus)){throw ex}}));Mod
                                                                    ^
Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:191:12)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:236:5)
    at Stream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Stream.endStream (/Users/aaronirons/Sites/haven_shopify/node_modules/gulp-usemin/node_modules/gulp-concat/index.js:90:10)
    at _end (/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-usemin/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/through/index.js:65:9)
    at Stream.stream.end (/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-usemin/node_modules/gulp-concat/node_modules/through/index.js:74:5)
    at Transform.onend (/Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-usemin/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:523:10)
    at Transform.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Transform.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at /Users/username/Sites/my_site/node_modules/gulp-usemin/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

This project has previous assembled just fine but now it just appears to randomly be choking on the dist build.

I am using Node 0.10.33.

Here is my gulp file:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var iconfont = require('gulp-iconfont');
var iconfontCss = require('gulp-iconfont-css');
var fontName = 'Icons';
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
// var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');
var fs = require('fs');
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include');
//var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

//needed becaues current gulp-sass errors with source maps on windows
var processWinPath = function(file) {
    var path = require('path');
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        file.path = path.relative('.', file.path);
        file.path = file.path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
    }
};

gulp.task("build-css", function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/main.scss')
        .on('data', processWinPath)
//        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: false,
            includePaths: ['./src/bower_components/foundation/scss/'],
            onError: function callback(err) {
                return notify().write(err);
            }
        }))
 //       .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});

gulp.task("build-css-no-source", function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true,
            includePaths: ['./src/bower_components/foundation/scss/'],
            onError: function(err) {
                return notify().write(err);
            }
        }))
        .pipe(prefix())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/'));
});


gulp.task('default', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src/"
        },
        files: ['src/*.html', 'src/css/*.css', 'src/js/*.js']
    });

    //run fileinclude on html changes
    gulp.watch(['*.html', 'includes/*.html'], ['fileinclude']);

    //compile css on sass changes
    gulp.watch(['src/scss/*.scss'], ["build-css"]);

    //need to figure out cert issue
    //gulp.watch(["img/*.jpg", "img/*.png", "img/*.gif", "img/*.jpeg"], ["compress-images"]);
});


gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
    gulp.src('*.html')
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: '@file'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['build-css-no-source', 'move-to-dist', 'minify-css']);

gulp.task('move-to-dist', ['build-css-no-source'], function() {

    var stream = gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(usemin({
            //  assetsDir:"./src/",
            css: ['concat'],
            js: [uglify()],
            jsmain: []
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));

    gulp.src('src/fonts/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts/'));
    gulp.src('src/img/**')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img/'));
    gulp.src('src/js/main.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))

    return stream;

});


gulp.task('minify-css', ['move-to-dist'], function() {
    fs.readFile('./dist/css/styles.css', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var content = data.toString();
        var index = content.indexOf("/* split file here */");
        var vendor = content.slice(0, index);
        var main = content.slice(index);
        fs.writeFile('./dist/css/styles.css', main, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('main is saved!');
        });
        fs.writeFile('./dist/css/vendor.min.css', vendor, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('vendor is saved!');
            return gulp.src('./dist/css/vendor.min.css')
                .pipe(minifyCSS())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
        });

    });


});

//run once after project has been created
gulp.task('init', function() {
    //move slick from bower components into project
    gulp.src('/bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss'));
    gulp.src('/bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/_settings.scss')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scss'));
});

gulp.task('make-iconfont', function() {
    gulp.src(['svg/*.svg'])
        .pipe(iconfontCss({
            fontName: fontName,
            fontPath: '../fonts/',
            targetPath: '../scss/_icons.scss'
        }))
        .pipe(iconfont({
            fontName: fontName,
            fontHeight: 1000,
            appendCodepoints: true,
            normalize: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/fonts/'));

});

var generateIconImport = function(inputfile) {
    fs.readFile(inputfile, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var content = data.toString();
        var html = "<div class='row icon-testing'><div class='small-12 columns'>";
        var re = /(icon\-\w.*(?=:))/g;
        var matches = content.match(re);
        matches.forEach(function(item) {
            html += "<div class='icon " + item + "'> " + item + "</div>";
        });
        console.log(html);
        fs.writeFile('src/fonts/icons.html', html + '</div></div>', function(err) {});
    });

}

gulp.task('view-iconfont', function() {
    generateIconImport("src/scss/_icons.scss");
});

gulp.task('clear', function (done) {
  return cache.clearAll(done);
});
```

Please help! This is about to drive me mad!